# How to subtract a month from an specific date format?

Tags: python, function, date, datetime, python-dateutil

I am trying to set a function that subtracts a month from an specific date format as an argument, and returns a date in the same specific date format,

This argument is given by today's month and year: `01/%m/%Y`.

Actual code:

```
from datetime import datetime
import dateutil.relativedelta

actual_date = datetime.now()
actual_date = "{}/{}/{}".format('01', actual_date.month, actual_date.year)


def set_date(actual_date):
    print(actual_date - dateutil.relativedelta.relativedelta(months=1))
```

Here's the output when `set_date()` is tested:

```
set_date(actual_date)

TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'relativedelta'
```

Expected output should look like this:

```
01/12/2020
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the first line, you get a `datetime`, then in the second line you build a `string` out of it. As a result, in `set_date` you get the mentioned error.

I suggest that you remove the second line and simply give the `datetime object` to `set_date` and do a `strftime` on the result:

```
actual_date = datetime.now()

def set_date(actual_date):
    result = actual_date - dateutil.relativedelta.relativedelta(months=1)
    print(datetime.strftime(result, "01/%m/%Y"))
```

However, if you really want to keep those conversions, you can use `strptime` for that purpose.

```
actual_date = datetime.now()
actual_date = datetime.strptime("{}/{}/{}".format('01', actual_date.month, actual_date.year), "%d/%m/%Y")


def set_date(actual_date):
    result = actual_date - dateutil.relativedelta.relativedelta(months=1)
    print(datetime.strftime(result, "%d/%m/%Y"))
```

Answer (score 2):

You're doing it in the wrong order.  Perform the date calculation first, and *then* convert to a string.

```
now = datetime.now()
one_month_ago = now - dateutil.relativedelta.relativedelta(months=1)
print("{}/{}/{}".format('01', one_month_ago.month, one_month_ago.year))
```

Comment: Could use `strftime` as well